# PHP Select for Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, select, smarty

Is it possible to make a second Select in an existing Select?

My php Code

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare('SELECT id,subcat_name FROM subcategory WHERE cat_id='.$cat_id.' ORDER BY sort DESC');
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $subcats[]=$row;
        }


        $smarty->assign('subcat',$subcats);
```

Template Code

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
                    {* start counter *}
                    {counter start=1 assign="cntval"}

                  <tr>
                    {foreach item=row  from=$subcat}

                    <td width="100%">


                                    <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="5">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top"><a class="subcatlink" href="index.php?view=subcat&id={$row->id}">{$row->subcat_name}(HERE I WANT INSERT THE RESULT FROM THE SECOND SELECT)</a></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>


                    </a>
                    </td>
                    {if ($cntval mod 2) eq 0}
                    </tr><tr>
                    {/if}
                    {* raise counter *}
                    {counter}
                    {/foreach}
                    </tr>
                 </table>
```

Where in the while Code can i insert a new select?
thanks for help

Comment: In the foreach in Smarty i must show another result from another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$row->id in your loop will serve as your key to your second result.

Make a $no_comments array with 'siteid' as your key so that you can access them in your smarty loop by calling $no_comments.$siteid.

Edit:
So you have your two arrays $comments and $sites (which you can also assign the id as the key, this way you won't have to assign a variable in Smarty loop).

In Smarty loop: 
You can't directly do $comments.$row->id. You have to assign the $row->id first like  {assign var='siteid' value=$row->id}, then you can call $comments.$siteid.

Answer (score 0):

ok now i have made this. The Results from the sites are listing but the Number of Comments i dont see @JoeS

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM sites WHERE subcat_id = '$subcat_id' AND status = 1 ORDER BY RAND()");
        $stmt->execute();
        $no=$stmt->rowCount();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $site_id = $row->id;
            $sites[]=$row;

            $stmt2 = $handler->prepare("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE site_id = '$site_id' AND status = 1");
            $stmt2->execute();
            $no_Comment=$stmt2->rowCount();
            $smarty->assign('no_Comment',$no_Comment);
        }


        $smarty->assign('site',$sites);
```

Comment: You are overriding the $no_comment in the loop. Basically the idea is that the 2nd result array should be $array[$id] = $no_comment;

Comment: And How can i assign this to smarty?
in the while or outside the while?

And how can i insert the array in the smarty template

Comment: Assign another variable? and call $no_comment.$siteid.

Answer (score 0):

Is this right?

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM sites WHERE subcat_id = '$subcat_id' AND status = 1 ORDER BY RAND()");
        $stmt->execute();
        $no=$stmt->rowCount();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $site_id = $row->id;
            $sites[]=$row;

            $stmt2 = $handler->prepare("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE site_id = '$site_id' AND status = 1");
            $stmt2->execute();
            $no_Comment=$stmt2->rowCount();
            $comments[$site_id]=$no_Comment;

        }

        $smarty->assign('site',$sites);
        $smarty->assign('comments',$comments);
```

Comment: NICE i had a mistake in the template but now it works fine

THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP 
This Answer helps me so much because now i can do many things i cant do before

Comment: i was false... 

In the Temlate File a have this here     `code`{$comments.$row->id}`code`

But i dont have an result

In Smarty DEbug Console i have this here
$comments
Origin: "Smarty object"  
Value
Array (2)
54 => 0
53 => 3

Comment: You can't do call $row->id. You have to assign it to a variable first, and call like what I said before: $a.$b.

Comment: is it possible that you can post a little bit of code

Comment: Oh I thought I saw that you know you can assign variables in Smarty. Do this: {assign var='siteid' value=$row->id}, then call $comments.$siteid

Comment: Thanks for Help "Youre My Hero"

I think you mean i must assign the siteid in php not in smarty

Comment: No you can do it in Smarty, that's exactly the syntax. In this case, I think you have to. Of course you can make your first array the same also have the id as the key, then you wouldn't have to in Smarty.